# Cognito Javascript SDK in multiple devices

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk, microservices, amazon-cognito

I've an application where user can be be accessible via Mobile Android and IOS devices (mobile apps). Also there's another web portal available for user to access . Therefore I wanted to know,

1. Should I duplicate the cognito SDK code in Android, IOS and Web
   application?
2. Or can this achieve by the single server side API
   end    point?
3. If so is there any special code for that?
4. With single API end point, is it secure to validate and store the sessions in device?

Here's the code i'm planning to use https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a server side API that accepts username and password and returns tokens or temporary credentials. However, not only will this be less secure, it will also mean you have to keep hitting this API every hour as your credentials expire. Many of the SDKs manage token refreshing internally. AWS amplify definitely does this. 
So although it might seem more convenient to have a single server side API, it is less secure and ends up being much more of a hassle.